# How do I solve the following integral using Cauchy Integral Theorem?

Tags: trigonometry, cauchy-integral-formula

I would like to solve the following integral using Cauchy Integral Theorem. I tried, but I got a different solution to Wolfram Alpha (Wolframs solution is **pi/60**). Help please!

$$\int_{0}^{2 \pi} {{\sin \theta} \over {34 - 16 \sin \theta}} d\theta$$

This is how I attempted the Cauchy Integral Theorem:

let $$ z =e^{i\theta} $$
$$\sin \theta = {1 \over 2i}(z - {1 \over z})$$
$$d\theta = {1 \over iz} dz$$
I proceed to substitute sin theta with the function of z and get the following expression, skipping ahead to get the following
$${i \over 2} \oint_{c}{{z - {1 \over z}} \over(8z^2 - 34iz-8)} dz$$
$${i \over 2} \oint_{c}{{z - {1 \over z}} \over(z -4i)(z -0.25i)} dz$$
I then applied the theorem to the only pole in the unit circle, Z - 0.25 i
and got the answer

$$17 \pi \over 15$$
Where did I do wrong? I've ran through the workings countless times but I cant seem to get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! This is great stuff! Gotta love Cauchy.

I agree with all of your work except your statement that the only pole is at $z=0.25i$. If you factor the top, you get an expression like
$$z-\frac{1}{z}=\frac{z^2-1}{z}$$
which gives you a pole also at $z=0$.

$$f(z)=\frac{i}{2}\frac{(z+1)(z-1)}{(z)(8z^2-34iz-8)}$$

Adding up the residues using Cauchy's Residue Theorem,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin{\theta}}{34-16\sin{\theta}}d\theta&=2\pi i\left(\text{Res}(f,z=0)+\text{Res}(f,z=0.25i)\right)\\
&=2\pi i\left(\frac{i}{16}-\frac{17i}{240}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{60}
\end{align*}

Comment: Ah.. I see! Thank you!

Should I be expecting the same results from real methods vs complex method like cauchy integral theorem?

I'm asking because popping the integral into Wolfram-Alpha shows that the answer is pi/60.

Comment: Indeed! In fact one of the most beautiful and useful applications of complex integration is the ability to solve difficult real integrals easily. For example, integrating a Gaussian without using the polar coordinates trick.

Comment: Oh! I see why you asked. I just suck at typing. Sorry, I hope I didn't confuse you. It really is pi/60.

Comment: Hey no worries! Would you happen to know how to solve the integral using Cauchy Integral Formula? I looked it up and found that Cauchy's Residue Theorem and Integral Formula are 2 different method of solving. I can't derive your solution using Integral Formula.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyIntegralFormula.html). They give what I believe to be a relevant example of how to use the integral formula. In your case, your initial contour is the unit circle, which can be deformed into three contours. One that integrates only around areas where the function is analytic, one tiny circle around the pole at the origin, and one tiny circle around the pole at .25i. Be sure to convince yourself that the three contours really do add up to the original contour, as in the Wolfram example.